# Export data regardless of pagination yii

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gridview, yii

I am in page 1 but I want to export all the data regardless of the pagination. Is there a way to get it? Currently I am saving the dataprovider in session because of the filter issues. I am using yii,bootstrap extended gridview and EExcelView (for csv and excel). Even I set this

```
  'disablePaging' => true
```

it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Most probably the problem is that disablePaging removes the pagiantion of the data provider but you(probably) setup filter conditions on the query before that and this cannot be removed by the extension.

Comment: That's also I am thinkinh. But I can't remove the filter condition.

Comment: can you post the code where you build the data provider for the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to find a solution. I separate the data provider for the export so that i can use the 'disabling' feature of the EExcelView.

My model looks like this:

//for export

```
Yii::app()->session['data_provider_export'] = new CActiveDataProvider('MyModel',array(
        'criteria' => $criteria));
```

//for gridview

```
return new CActiveDataProvider('MyModel',array(
        'criteria' =>$criteria,
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),
            'route'=> '',
        ),
                        'sort' => array(
                            'attributes' => array(

                            ),
                        ),
    ));
```